# Why is my codeigniter database query returning NULL on the field it is successfully searching on

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am really confused as to why I am getting a NULL value for my item_id which is a required field in my table and is what I am searching on in the first place,

here is the relevant part of my controller:

```
$item_id=$this->uri->segment(4);
$page_data['row'] = $this->item_model->get_item($item_id, TRUE);
var_dump($page_data['row']);
```

and here is my model:

```
function get_item($id, $admin=FALSE){
        $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('item_entries')
            ->where('item_entries.item_id', $id)
            ->join('item_categories_rel', 'item_categories_rel.item_id = item_entries.item_id')
            ->join('item_descriptions', 'item_descriptions.item_id = item_entries.item_id')
            ->join('ratings_total', 'ratings_total.item_id = item_entries.item_id')
            ->join('item_categories', 'item_categories.cat_id = item_categories_rel.cat_id');
        if($admin==TRUE){
            $this->db
                ->join('admin_item_alerts', 'admin_item_alerts.item_id = item_entries.item_id')
                ->join('item_object_code', 'item_object_code.item_id = item_entries.item_id', 'left');
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

and here is the output of the var_dump:

```
array(21) { ["item_id"]=> NULL ["item_name"]=> string(9) "MediaInfo" ["item_img"]=> string(13) "mediaInfo.gif" ["item_link"]=> string(42) "http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/" ["is_code"]=> string(1) "n" ["is_pick"]=> string(1) "n" ["is_quicklink"]=> string(1) "n" ["date_added"]=> string(19) "2010-10-01 00:03:04" ["rel_id"]=> string(3) "132" ["cat_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["item_desc"]=> string(9) "desc_here" ["site_rating"]=> string(3) "3.0" ["urate_ave"]=> string(3) "0.0" ["parent_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["gparent_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["sort_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["cat_name"]=> string(2) "PC" ["cat_slug"]=> string(2) "pc" ["date_checked"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["UpCode"]=> string(1) "N" ["item_code"]=> NULL }
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is doing this to me :( ?

Comment: Don't you get several responses for the field item_id? I would rename the response by AS...

Comment: Indeed i do if I run it as SQL through phpmyadmin - but this isn't causing a problem in any other queries with several responses for a field. How do I do rename the response using as in AR??

Comment: You just put it in the select statement just as normal mysql syntax $this->db->select('item_id AS myid');

Comment: When you have multiple columns with the same name in a query result, `$query->row_array()` will only retain the value for the last column with that name. If in your other queries, the last instance of the same-named column turned out to contain the value you expect, it is not surprising that you did not see any adverse effects.

Comment: My final join may or may not contain a matching entry. Moving this join forward in the chain solves the issue, would this be bad practice? Would I be better going with the $this->db->select('item_id AS myid') solution? Does it matter?

Comment: Is it worth someone presenting the response to this as an answer so that I can accept? @jtheman & lanzz, thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you select several columns with the name `item_id` hence the results will fetch the last column with name item_id. To target the problem use you need to either not select the joined table's item_id or use aliases for your main tables item_id:

```
  $this->db->select('item_entries.item_id AS the_id')
```

(of course you will need to include also the other columns here with table.* syntax)